# Python Regex for a Specific Word

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, extract

I have the below texts in a column called actions.

```
"Why don't you clean this table : J$CLAB"
"http("J$MANG.create"): 21/01/06 23:24:05 INFO"
```

i would like to extract the words that start with J$... till the end. e.g. J$MANG & add it in a new column.

here is what i have done so far, not working as needed

```
file['fileName'] = [re.split(r'[^J$A-Z\.$]|[^J$A-Z\s$]', val.strip()) for val in file['action']]
file['fileName']  = [' '.join(val) for val in file['fileName']]
```

any suggestions. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can  use

```
file['fileName']  = file['action'].str.extract(r'\b(J\$\w*)', expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5n0dLd/1)

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(J\$\w*)` - Group 1: `J` and zero or more word chars.